# How can I find the method that is for an event

Tags: c#, delegates

In a C# source there is something like this:

```
public event UnloadHandler Unload;
public delegate void UnloadHandler();
```

then in the program there are calls to Unload() , when I hit F12 to see the implementation it again jump to that event declaration. So how can I find the real body of this Unload() method?

Answer (score 4):

`Unload` is not a method, it's an [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx) -- it does not *have* a "real body".

When the event is raised, any handlers attached to it will be executed in turn. You can get the list of attached handlers from code inside the class through [`Delegate.GetInvocationList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.getinvocationlist.aspx), but you cannot magically jump to the implementing code.

What you *can* do is find the places where event handlers are attached with the syntax `Unload += /* something */` by searching the source; this will tell you exactly what is scheduled to run when the event is raised.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click and select "Find Usages".  Somewhere something should be assigning a method to the Unload event (there could be more than one).  It will look something like

```
this.Unload += new UnloadHandler(form_Unload);
```

or

```
this.Unload += form_Unload;
```

You can then hit f12 on the handler that's added.

Comment: Shift-F12 should do the same in VS 2010

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is by hitting F12 on UnloadHandler declaration. Also could be nice is if you have Visual Studio, just try something like Unload += (TAB) - and visual studio auto-generates method stubs for you.

Cheers,
Ivan