# Event handler is not defined in namespace and yet is not null.Why?

Tags: c#, binding, delegates, devexpress, eventhandler

I am trying to understand the code in a Dev Express example 
[here][1]

The code I am trying to understand is

```
    public event EventHandler RtfTextChanged;

    private void richEditControl_ModifiedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if(RtfTextChanged != null)  // how come this is not null?
            RtfTextChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);  // break at this point to display call stack.
    }
```

[Update]
Some how RtfTextChanged is being set by the RichEditControl due to it's name.
If I rename my RtfTextChanged to RtfTextChanged2 then RtfTextChanged2 does equal null.

The call stack shows that binding and reflection are involved

```
WinSolution.Module.Win.dll!WinSolution.Module.Win.RichEditUserControl.RtfText.get() Line 45 C#
[Native to Managed Transition]  
System.dll!System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.GetValue(object component = {WinSolution.Module.Win.RichEditUserControl})    Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Binding.GetPropValue()    Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Binding.PullData(bool reformat = false, bool force = false)   Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Binding.Target_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Unknown
WinSolution.Module.Win.dll!WinSolution.Module.Win.RichEditUserControl.richEditControl_ModifiedChanged(object sender = {DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.RichEditControl}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 63   C#
DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.v15.1.dll!DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.RichEditControl.RaiseModifiedChanged()    Unknown
DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.v15.1.dll!DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.RichEditControl.OnModifiedChanged(object sender = {DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.RichEditControl}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Unknown
DevExpress.RichEdit.v15.1.Core.dll!DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Internal.InnerRichEditDocumentServer.RaiseModifiedChanged()  Unknown
DevExpress.RichEdit.v15.1.Core.dll!DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Internal.InnerRichEditDocumentServer.OnModifiedChanged(object sender = {DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Model.DocumentModel}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs})   Unknown
DevExpress.RichEdit.v15.1.Core.dll!DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Model.DocumentModel.RaiseModifiedChanged()   Unknown
DevExpress.RichEdit.v15.1.Core.dll!DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Model.DocumentModel.OnHistoryModifiedChanged(object sender = {DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Model.History.RichEditDocumentHistory}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs})   Unknown
DevExpress.Office.v15.1.Core.dll!DevExpress.Office.History.DocumentHistory.RaiseModifiedChanged()   Unknown
DevExpress.Office.v15.1.Core.dll!DevExpress.Office.History.DocumentHistory.EndTrackModifiedChanged()    Unknown
DevExpress.Office.v15.1.Core.dll!DevExpress.Office.History.DocumentHistory.InternalAdd(DevExpress.Office.History.HistoryItem item = {DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Model.History.RichEditCompositeHistoryItem})   Unknown
DevExpress.Office.v15.1.Core.dll!DevExpress.Office.History.DocumentHistory.Add(DevExpress.Office.History.HistoryItem item = {DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Model.History.RichEditCompositeHistoryItem})   Unknown
DevExpress.RichEdit.v15.1.Core.dll!DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Model.History.RichEditDocumentHistory.Add(DevExpress.Office.History.HistoryItem item = {DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Model.History.RichEditCompositeHistoryItem}) Unknown
DevExpress.Office.v15.1.Core.dll!DevExpress.Office.History.DocumentHistory.CommitTransaction()  Unknown
DevExpress.Office.v15.1.Core.dll!DevExpress.Office.History.DocumentHistory.EndTransaction() Unknown
DevExpress.Office.v15.1.Core.dll!DevExpress.Office.History.HistoryTransaction.Dispose(bool disposing = true)    Unknown
DevExpress.Office.v15.1.Core.dll!DevExpress.Office.History.HistoryTransaction.Dispose() Unknown
DevExpress.RichEdit.v15.1.Core.dll!DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Commands.TransactedMultiCommand.ForceExecute(DevExpress.Utils.Commands.ICommandUIState state = {DevExpress.Utils.Commands.DefaultCommandUIState})    Unknown
DevExpress.Data.v15.1.dll!DevExpress.Utils.Commands.Command.Execute()   Unknown
DevExpress.RichEdit.v15.1.Core.dll!DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Keyboard.NormalKeyboardHandler.FlushPendingTextInputCore(string pendingInput = "x")  Unknown
DevExpress.RichEdit.v15.1.Core.dll!DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Keyboard.NormalKeyboardHandler.PerformFlushPendingTextInput(string pendingInput = "x")   Unknown
DevExpress.RichEdit.v15.1.Core.dll!DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Keyboard.NormalKeyboardHandler.FlushPendingTextInput()   Unknown
DevExpress.RichEdit.v15.1.Core.dll!DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Internal.InnerRichEditControl.FlushPendingTextInput()    Unknown
DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.v15.1.dll!DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.RichEditControl.ForceFlushPendingTextInput()  Unknown
DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.v15.1.dll!DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.RichEditControl.OnFlushPendingTextInputTimerTick(object sender = {Interval = 100}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs})   Unknown
DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.v15.1.dll!DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Drawing.LeakSafeEventRouter.OnFlushPendingTextInputTimerTick(object sender = {Interval = 100}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs})   Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg = 275, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)  Unknown
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.IntPtr dwComponentID, int reason, int pvLoopData)  Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason = -1, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context = {System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext})   Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) Unknown
DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.v15.1.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.WinApplication.DoApplicationRun() Unknown
DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.v15.1.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.WinApplication.Start()    Unknown
WinSolution.Win.exe!WinSolution.Win.Program.Main() Line 46  C#
[Native to Managed Transition]  
Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()    Unknown
```

I see inside the RichEditControl source

```
#if !SL
[DevExpressXtraRichEditLocalizedDescription("RichEditControlRtfTextChanged")]
#endif
    public event EventHandler RtfTextChanged {
        add { if (InnerControl != null) InnerControl.RtfTextChanged += value; }
        remove { if (InnerControl != null) InnerControl.RtfTextChanged -= value; }
    }
```

Comment: looking at @Jon answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775122/how-can-i-find-the-method-that-is-for-an-event , so an event does not have a "real" body.   I will try to get the list of attached handlers.

Comment: Keeping it real super simple: when you attach an event handler to an event, a function pointer (delegate) is added to the method invocation list of the event. This is a runtime thing, the function pointer locates where in memory that function resides, this location can change each time the application is run. Does that help?

Comment: So the code "public event EventHandler RtfTextChanged;"  is "attaching an event handler to an event"  ?

Comment: It would really help me to see an example of  how RtfTextChanged can be set by a different assembly so as to be not null in this one.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if I want to raise an event in another class, then I need to set up a hander for that event.

I do this by using the event's name

```
public event EventHandler RtfTextChanged;
```

The fact that something in the other class is already subscribing means that the handler will not be null.